# password manager addon for firefox by SITE not by domain

Tags: firefox, password-manager, plug-in

We have many sites in our network with many different passwords for each site,
unfortunately firefox,chrome,edge, all of them keep a single password no matter what the site is as long as the domain is the same, so for mycms.company.com i have one password and I want another for mySAP.company.com, all browsers just keep one password and assume company.com is all that matters, I need to keep many different ones.

Comment: Do you have any link for this site

Comment: it is intranet only, but you can try it in any website you have in your own server, say you have employess.intranet.com and also visitors.intranet.com , if you create a login and want to save it in your browser it will only save 1 no matter if you use visitors or employees site.